# How do I reach the rooms east of "A Jump Too Far"?

Tags: antichamber

It seems like I have only two rooms left (got the red gun), *Laying The Foundation* (top left in the map; I know what the problem is, there) and *A Jump Too Far* (in the middle). On other screenshots I have seen at least three more rooms in the section marked red, but I can't find any route I haven't taken a dozen times.
Is it something incredibly obvious?! (or is this through the door marked *The End*? It's still blocked…)

[image: Map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the red gun to unblock and then to go through the door marked "The End".

Look at the floor, and pay attention to details, like a small gap.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that it is perfectly possible to get through here with only the yellow gun. I wouldn't recommend it though as it is far easier to complete with the red gun. Just use the gap in the floor and yellow gun to drag the blocks up/use the red gun to grow blocks destroying the blocks preventing you from proceeding.